# Pandas: Convert only numbers in dataframe to numeric, keep everything else

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Source Dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', '2.0', '3.0'], 'y': ['4.0', 'b', '6.0']})

    x   y
0   a   4.0
1   2.0 b
2   3.0 6.0
```

### First Try (use 'coerce')

If I use 'coerce' to handle strings, they will be replaced by NaN

```
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str).str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce'))

    x   y
0   NaN 4.0
1   2.0 NaN
2   3.0 6.0
```

### Second Try (use 'ignore')

If I use 'ignore' to handle strings, the whole column does not get converted (numbers still stay as text strings)

```
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str).str.replace(',',''), errors='ignore'))

    x   y
0   a   4.0
1   2.0 b
2   3.0 6.0
```

Comment: so you want mixed datatypes but dtype should be int/float for the series?

Comment: Good point - so each columns has a dtype. In that case, yes it should be mixed. i want to export this dataframe to excel later on. And numbers should appear as numbers there. That's actually what I'm trying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is expected output, because if check [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) you can see:

> errors : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}, default 'raise'
>
> If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception
> If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaN
> If 'ignore', then invalid parsing **will return the input**

Possible solution is replace missing values by original values - but get mixed numeric with strings values like pointed @anky_91 in comments:

```
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str).str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce'))
```

---

```
df3 = df2.fillna(df1)
```

Or:

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Check types:

```
print (df3.applymap(type))
                 x                y
0    <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>
2  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Yes, I think it was a dump question actually because the data type is assigne to a column, And I cannot have mixed datatypes. I was confused because I want to export it to excel laterand numbers should show up as numeric.

Comment: Actually, you solution converts the column into numeric and then back to object. Which makes sense but does not help me. When I export to excel later its string again.

Comment: @Lorenz - Yes, unfortunately, because DataFrame after converting have numeric with strings - is possible check it by `print (df3.applymap(type))`

Comment: Actually, this worked. Numbers are now numeric in excel. And all text strings are kept. Awesome. Thank you so much!